# How to make sure every string from particular xml is translated in another xml in Android? Any good practices?

Tags: android, internationalization, multilingual

Lets say i have 2 languages in 2 different xmls, when I develop my app, I create more strings in strings.xml. Sometimes I don't want to translate it right away, sometimes I can forget. How can I later check and compare both xmls and make sure everything is translated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Android Lint,

> http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

It specifically checks for just that case.

From,

> http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks
>
> ### MissingTranslation
>
> Summary: Checks for incomplete translations where not all strings are translated
>
> Priority: 8 / 10
> Severity: Fatal
> Category: Correctness:Messages
>
> If an application has more than one locale, then all the strings
> declared in one language should also be translated in all other
> languages.
>
> By default this detector allows regions of a language to just provide
> a subset of the strings and fall back to the standard language
> strings. You can require all regions to provide a full translation by
> setting the environment variable ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.

If you are using a recent ADT, you can run it directly from Eclipse by right clicking your project > android tools > run lint.